# Any Way to Speed / Python-ize Five Nested for() Loops?

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

(Note: I read a few other related questions on this site, but I don't think they apply to my specific circumstance; if they do, my apologies.)

Problem: I am trying to derive photometric parameters for a specific location on a planetary body.  This is an extremely non-linear problem and the photometric parameters interact in non-linear ways.  I've reduced the problem to 5 of the most important parameters, and I've talked with experts in the field who have told me that, yes, there is no way to analytically solve these equations and all they do is parameter-space sweeps.  The idea is to have a broad parameter space first, then refine it as parameters are converged upon (this sentence is not yet written into the code snippet below).

Because I need to search through a 5D parameter space, I have written this as five nested for() loops.  Each time the inner-most loop iterates, it checks the result against the actual data, determines if the RMS is less than the previous best, and saves those parameters if it is.

Question: Is there any way to speed this up?  It is painfully slow, slower than the "Igor Pro" language I was programming in before (but Igor can't be called by Python, and all my other code is in Python).  I can't think of a way to "Pythonize" things since it has quite a bit of math for each unique parameter value and because it does the testing with each iteration.  The other "only" thing I can think of is to coarsen the parameter space further with each iteration so that, for example, it would not need to do 10^5 iterations below, but I run the risk of missing sensitive local minima if I do that.

```
#Iteration 1, start with a wide aray of possible parameters.
parameter_w  = 0.0
parameter_b0 = 0.0
parameter_h  = 1E-10
parameter_b  = 0.0
parameter_c  = 0.0
iterator_w   = 0.10
iterator_b0  = 0.25
iterator_h   = 0.10
iterator_b   = 0.10
iterator_c   = 0.10
maxits_w     = 10+1
maxits_b0    = 10+1
maxits_h     = 10+1
maxits_b     = 10+1
maxits_c     = 10+1
lastbest     = 9999

#Do the parameter space search.
for counter_c in range(0,maxits_c):
    parameter_c_test = parameter_c + iterator_c*counter_c
    for counter_b in range(0,maxits_b):
        parameter_b_test = parameter_b + iterator_b*counter_b
        for counter_h in range(0,maxits_h):
            parameter_h_test = parameter_h + iterator_h*counter_h
            for counter_b0 in range(0,maxits_b0):
                parameter_b0_test = parameter_b0 + iterator_b0*counter_b0
                for counter_w in range(0,maxits_w):
                    parameter_w_test = parameter_w + iterator_w*counter_w
                    
                    Vgamma = math.sqrt(1-parameter_w_test)
                    SurfaceRoughnessFunction = 1 #equals 1 if theta, the roughness parameter, is 0
                    
                    #Modified incidence and emission angles (above eq. 2 in Hapke (2002)).
                    mu0 = [math.cos(Incidence[i]*3.1415926/180.) for i in range(len(Incidence))]
                    mu  = [math.cos(Emission[i] *3.1415926/180.) for i in range(len(Emission ))]
                    
                    #Coefficient ... normalization factor?
                    part1 = [parameter_w_test / 4. * mu0[i] / (mu0[i] + mu[i])  for i in range(len(DN))]
                    
                    #Shadow-Hiding Opposition Effect (SHOE) --eq 28 with 29 from Hapke (2002)
                    part2 = [1 + parameter_b0_test / (1 + math.tan(Phase[i]/2.*3.1415926/180.)/parameter_h_test) for i in range(len(DN))]
                    
                    #Double Henyey-Greenstein Function.
                    part3 = [(1+parameter_c_test)*(1-parameter_b_test**2) / (2* (1+2*parameter_b_test*math.cos(Phase[i]*3.1415926/180.)+parameter_b_test**2)**(1.5) ) + (1-parameter_c_test)*(1-parameter_b_test**2) / (2* (1-2*parameter_b_test*math.cos(Phase[i]*3.1415926/180.)+parameter_b_test**2)**(1.5) ) for i in range(len(DN))]
                    
                    #The "H" functions. --eq. 2 in Hapke (2002)
                    part4 =  [(1+2*mu0[i]) / (1+2*Vgamma*mu0[i]) * (1+2*mu[i]) / (1+2*Vgamma*mu[i]) for i in range(len(DN))]
                    
                    #Eq 38 from Hapke (2002).
                    DN_model = [DN[i] - part1[i] * ( part2[i]*part3[i] + part4[i] - 1) * SurfaceRoughnessFunction  for i in range(len(DN))]
                    MS = 0
                    for i in range(len(DN)):
                        MS += DN_model[i]**2
                    RMS = math.sqrt(MS/len(DN))
                    if RMS < lastbest:
                        parameter_w_best = parameter_w_test
                        parameter_b0_best= parameter_b0_test
                        parameter_h_best = parameter_h_test
                        parameter_b_best = parameter_b_test
                        parameter_c_best = parameter_c_test
                        lastbest = RMS
                        print(RMS, parameter_w_best, parameter_b0_best, parameter_h_best, parameter_b_best, parameter_c_best)
```

Comment: Exhausting all possibilities in a 5-d parameter space is inherently slow, even if you shorten the code. Check out `itertools.product`.

Comment: Is a binary search of each parameter possible? This could lead to some performance improvements, assuming your output can specify that the end result is "too high" or "too low".

Comment: Questions about improving working code are more appropriate for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably be using numpy arrays, because operations on them are just generally faster. To quote an article, "as array size gets close to 5,000,000, Numpy gets around 120 times faster [than regular lists]".

Because this is a 5-D search, you will end up with a lot of repeated calculations. One way to circumvent this is to use memoization. You could define repeated sub-calculations that only use a few of the parameters as functions, then store the result of each of these functions for previously seen parameters. This turns these function calls into extremely fast operations, which could save some execution time.
Fortunately, python makes this really easy: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache

*As a side note, be sure to optimize your memoization space using a profiler - otherwise you will probably run out of RAM.

You should also consider profiling your code using linux to see if you get minor performance improvements: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ryzen3-windows-linux&num=8

I would also recoment comparing cPython performance with PyPy. You might be able to get your program to run a lot faster with PyPy, but it's hard to be sure without comparing benchmarks for your specific use-case.
https://speed.pypy.org/

Comment: To add to the NumPy point, a big part of the reason that Python lists are slower than NumPy arrays is that Python lists are arrays of references to disparate objects on the heap with no known common type. So you have to jump to another part of the memory and inspect type for EVERY element. NumPy arrays store its data directly and enforces a common type. The downside (?) is that you have to learn how to write vectorized code where you do operations on arrays, rather than looping through arrays (which is also slower because of Python). Numba's `njit` speeds up loopy code but it has limitations.

Comment: Thanks. I first applied your point about repeated calculations, since I didn't realize before that several components only depend on 2 parameters, so I made caches. Sped things 3x. Then I converted to NumPy, and that sped things by 100x. Enough that I could shrink intervals and still run things in ~10 min. RAM isn't an issue (yet), but I watch it. Since ~10 min is more than reasonable at the moment, I have not tried to implement your other suggestions, as those look more complicated.